# How to access a variable from a function in an imported file

Tags: python

So I have a file, let's name it main.py

In it, I have imported an external file, which we will call ext.py

Now let's say that these are the contents of ext.py:

```
def how():
    tangerine = 1
```

And let's say these are the contents of main.py:

```
import ext
print #Not sure what or how
```

What I want to know is what to do to print out the tangerine variable via the main file.
Something like this: print ext.how().tangerine?
If I type in ext.tangerine it doesn't work as the tangerine is defined only in the how() function.

Please help as I really need it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to using a global - return the value of tangerine from the function-:

```
def how():
     tangerine = 1    
     return tangerine
```

in main.py-:

```
 import ext
 print ext.how()
```

Comment: the how() function (or in my actual case the date() function) is much bigger and doesn't have only that as code, so if I understood your code well enough, this would create a mayhem.
Or would it print only the stuff you returned?
Thank you!

Comment: @user2154354 It would only print the stuff you returned, so no worries.

Comment: It doesn't work.
What I need to do is input some files, including two dates (dat of arrival and date of departure).
So in one file, I input everything, and at the point when I input dates, it goes to a completely different file where the whole algorithm is for checking if the dates are taken.
If yes:
    tangerine = 1
    return tangerine
elif no:
    tangerine = 0
    return tangerine

And then in the main file, I input some more, and this is how it is written:

if file2.function() == 1
    print "Dates taken"
elif file2.function() == 0
    write all info to files

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a class.

```
def how():
    tangerine = 1
```

will always have the value 1. If you make it accessible globally as mentioned by the other posters, the variable will be accessible in the global namespace, which means every time you modify the variable outside the method, the functionality of your function may suffer, because it's dependend on a 'global state'. Most likely unwanted and bad things may happen.

Using classes/objects isn't difficult:

```
class Know(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.tangerine = t
    def how(self):
        self.tangerine += 1

iknow = Know(0)
iknow.how()

youknow.Know(9)
youknow.how()
print youknow.tangerine
>>> 10
print iknow.tangerine
>>> 1
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I forgot to mention that I do not know and simply can't understand classes (I've tried).

Comment: classes are variables on steroids. variables with their own functions (=methods). there's nothing complicated about them in normal use-cases. try: `'i use classes'.upper()` in idle.

Comment: No seriously, I really can't understand them with the __init__ and self and object and all those things.
This is where I'm learning python from:
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

Comment: don't get frustrated! It'll come eventually! ;-)